# A combining form which denotes twenty

Tags: single-word-requests

We use the word "deca" as a combining form to denote 10 like in decade or decahedron.

What is the combining form of twenty? 
Is there really a word to symbolize 20?

Comment: Did you do any research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_numerical_multiplier

Comment: For use in what context? That's the kicker, here. Decaliter is used because the metric system does have things in tens. I don't know anything in everyday parlance that is expressed in units of twenty.

Answer (score 1):

There is a form "[viginti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viginti-)-" from the Latin for 20, but it is rare. There is also the Greek "[icosa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/icosa-)-", which is also rare. Either form is rare enough that they might not be understood.

Comment: I’d say it’s absolutely nonexistent outside of the two words (well, one at least) listed on Wiktionary. I’ve never heard it used in any word other than _vigintillion_. _Icosa-_ (or _eicosa-_) is still rare, but much less so, in my experience.

Comment: Agreed, @JanusBahsJacquet - the prefixes exist but they are rare and may not be understood.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal

Comment: For use in what context? decaliter may be common as liters are metric and go by tens, but what "goes by twenties"? Please tell me....

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The common form of 20 in mathematic terms is [Icosa-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/icosa-)

as used for [Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) and [icosasphere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/icosasphere)

Icosa-core used for [Twenty core microchips](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/icosa-core)

There are truncated Icosapods (housing etc.) and in chemistry we have 366,319 isomers as [icosanes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/icosane#English)